# How do I get this each loop to apply to every item?

Tags: ruby

I'm working on a problem called Image Blur. I need to have my code take items (either 1s or 0s) from a 2D array and, for every 1, change the adjacent 0s to 1s. My code thus far does this well to the first 1 that it comes across, but for some reason it does not loop over the others.

```
class Image
  def initialize(image)
    @values = image
  end

  def find_ones
    ones = []
    @values.each_with_index do |row, row_index|
      row.each_with_index do |pixel, column_index|
        if pixel == 1
          coord = [row_index, column_index]
          ones << coord
        end
        puts "#{pixel} #{row_index} #{column_index}" if pixel == 1
      end
    end
    ones
  end

  def transform
    ones = find_ones
    ri = ones[0][0]
    ci = ones[0][1]
    ones.each do 
      @values[ri + 1][ci] = 1 if (ri + 1) <= 3
      @values[ri - 1][ci] = 1 if (ri - 1) >= 0
      @values[ri][ci + 1] = 1 if (ci + 1) <= 3
      @values[ri][ci - 1] = 1 if (ci - 1) >= 0
    end
  end


 def output_image
    @values.each do |row|
      puts row.join
    end
  end
end


image = Image.new([
  [0, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0]
])

image.transform
image.output_image
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well your `ones.each do` goes through the `ones` but ignores them, since your block doesn't have parameters. You essentially just use `ones` to determine **how often** to run the block.

Your

```
ri = ones[0][0]
ci = ones[0][1]
ones.each do
```

should be

```
ones.each do |ri, ci|
```

I'm surprised you got `find_ones` right (where you do something similar) but do something so strange in `transform` (setting `ri` and `ci` like that).